# Can't get this.var to bind correct data in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

Two Important Notes:
1. My goal is to AVOID using $scope in this case since it's my understanding that impedes the new "controller as" syntax.
2. My problem is likely a variable scope issue and so perhaps just clarifying the proper JS way might solve the problem.

Nevermind the exports, I'm working with browserify in my workflow.

I have this *working* code:

```
exports.IntroCtrl = function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.introData = [];
    $http.get('data/intro.json')
        .success(function(res){
            $scope.introData = res;
    });

};
```

That ideally I'd like to work as something like this, for the sake of using the "controller as" syntax.

```
exports.IntroCtrl = function($http) {
    this.introData = [];
    $http.get('data/intro.json')
        .success(function(res){
            introData = res;
    });

};
```

The problem is that the $http service seems to be executing before  my initial this.introData declaration since I get a variable not defined error.

If tell `this.introData = $http.get…` then it returns an array of 5 objects that I can't access and intro.json only contains 4.

Thanks for any guidance/help.

Comment: Avoid using $scope?... I don't get it. How is that related to 'controller as' ?

Comment: Why exactly would you prefer using the `controller as` syntax instead of just using the `$scope`?

Comment: You probably just want `this.introData = res;`

Comment: @Pak - I maybe it's not related, can you use the "controller as " syntax with a $scoped variable in angular? I couldn't get it to use.

Comment: @runTarm - For a rare situation where I may want a nested controller, I'd rather be able to access the data anywhere with dot notation.

Comment: @JB Nizet - Wouldn't that bind introData to the $http object?

Comment: @motleyev you have to remember `this` of controller instance by something like `var self = this;`, then use it in the success callback like `self.introData = res;`.

Comment: +1 to runTarm. in the success callback this is actually the window object. This is why I find $scope sooo convenient. No need for this horrible `this` handling. @runTarm: you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remember `this` variable that reference the controller instance, and use it later in the success callback like this:

```
exports.IntroCtrl = function($http) {
  this.introData = [];

  var ctrl = this; // remember 'this', the controller instance, to use in the success callback below

  $http.get('data/intro.json')
    .success(function (res) {
      ctrl.introData = res;
    });
};
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First of all create a service for the http call. It is very convenient way to get the callback in the controller and then assign your controller as variables. Here is the factory for you:

Factory

```
app.factory('getDataService',function ($http) {
    return {
        getData:function(callback){
            $http.get('data/intro.json')
                 .success(callback)
            });

        }
    }
});
```

In your controller you get inject the getDataService and bind the data like this:

Controller:

```
app.controller('testController',['getDataService',function(testDataService){
    this.introData = [];
    testDataService.getData(function(data){
        this.introData = data;
    });
}]);
```

Here you need to bind the introData of the controller function.

Comment: I also really liked this answer, too. Perhaps this is using the power of Angular more - @runTarm I think addressed the specific problem more directly.

Comment: Thanks @motleydev for the appreciation, I think creating services rather than having http call direct in the controller would fail the use case of reusability. While using services you can reuse the code a lot thereby reducing the number of lines and making the code more maintainable at the same time.

Comment: @motleydev: Not changing your mind to switch to this answer? :)

Comment: Totally impacted me enough to implement - but in the "fairness of the game" - the other participant beat you in time submission with a usable answer. :) But I absolutely appreciate your answer! :)

Comment: Ok then the other option is just to upvote if you implemented this one...that will be fair to me